# Is it possible to work with BDE created tables in C#?

Tags: c#, database, bde

I have some tables being used with the Borland Database Engine that I need access to in C#. But I don't see the BDE as an available Data Source. Is this because it's not doable or something else. If anyone has any info or links to provide on how this is done I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would imagine you would have to use the ODBC drivers for it.

If you are using the ODBC then you will need to search for how to create a connection string for it.

Look into

System.Data.ODBC

and

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection

Ignore the above, it should be OLEDB See the link below.  In some of the links I found there are some Borland Purists who say "why work in c# when you can keep it all the same technology stack"  but I think thats the same with most languages, theres purists in them all.

I also just found this link

[Connecting to BDE Paradox from C#](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Connecting-to-a-PARADOX-DB-with-C-(Vista-XP).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link Peter! That will get me started.

Answer (score 3):

What is the extension of the file that you are trying to access? The BDE could work with several file types: FoxPro/dBase, Paradox, ASCII and sometimes even Access. Outside of Paradox, you should have no problem using C# to do the access. Like Peter says, ODBC is probably the easiest to access a paradox file from C#, you just need to find a Paradox ODBC driver.

Comment: @MarcBernier it is paradox